# What is the original English text of this Spanish text from Harry Potter about Harry being forced to wear a disgusting old sweater of Dudley's?

Tags: harry-potter

I'm trying to help a Spanish speaker who is reading *Harry Potter* in Spanish.

> Otra vez, tía Petunia había tratado de meterlo dentro de un asqueroso suéter viejo de Dudley. Mientras más intentaba pasárselo por la cabeza, más pequeña se volvía la prenda; hasta que finalmente le habría quedado como un guante a una muñeca, pero no a Harry.

Here is a rough translation of the Spanish into English:

> Again, Aunt Petunia had tried to stuff him into a disgusting old sweater of Dudley's. The more he tried to pass his head through it, the smaller the garment became; until finally it would have been like a glove to a doll, but not to Harry.

**What is the actual *original* English text for this passage?**

Comment: Could you provide the original Spanish as well?

Comment: @Adfamant - Otra vez, tía Petunia había tratado de meterlo dentro de un asqueroso suéter viejo de Dudley. Mientras más intentaba pasárselo por la cabeza, más pequeña se volvía la prenda; hasta que finalmente le habría quedado como un guante a una muñeca, pero no a Harry.

Comment: Well, there really is a lot missing there, it seems. The whole description of the sweater, wow!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's this text from the first book, *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*:

> Another time, Aunt Petunia had been trying to force him into a revolting old jumper of Dudley’s (brown with orange bobbles). The harder she tried to pull it over his head, the smaller it seemed to become, until finally it might have fitted a glove puppet, but certainly wouldn’t fit Harry.